# standard binary maxBy function

Tags: generics, max, comparable, standard-library, kotlin

I generalized the following code:

```
fun max(that: Type): Type = if (this.rank() < that.rank()) that else this
```

to this:

```
fun max(that: Type): Type = maxBy(this, that) { it.rank() }

fun maxBy<T, U : Comparable<U>>(a: T, b: T, f: (T) -> U): T
    = if (f(a) < f(b)) b else a
```

Is there a function like `maxBy` in Kotlin's standard library? I could only find one for arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin stdlib has [`max`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/kotlin.-iterable/max.html) and [`maxBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/kotlin.-iterable/max-by.html) [extension functions on `Iterable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/kotlin.-iterable)

The signature of `max` is:

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> Iterable<T>.max(): T?
```

The signature of `maxBy` is:

```
fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> Iterable<T>.maxBy(
    selector: (T) -> R
): T?
```

Either work with a comparable value.  `maxBy` uses a lambda to create the value that is comparable from each item.

Here is a test case showing both in action:

```
@Test fun testSO30034197() {
    // max:
    val data = listOf(1, 5, 3, 9, 4)
    assertEquals(9, data.max())

    // maxBy:
    data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
    val people = listOf(Person("Felipe", 25), Person("Santiago", 10), Person("Davíd", 33))
    assertEquals(Person("Davíd", 33), people.maxBy { it.age })
}
```

See also:  [Kotlin API Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this since Kotlin 1.1 is a [maxOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/max-of.html) method.